# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-service

I have a running service of application. When user return to app I check if servise is running and if it's true I try to connect with this servise and show fragment with some data. But sometimes I get this mistake:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1433)
       at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
       at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:667)
       at com.fjuul.fjuul.MainActivity.showGPSFragment(MainActivity.java:712)
```

try to connect with servise

```
private void connectService() {
    registerFitnessReceiver();
    sConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            if (service != null) {
                callGPSFragment(status, mapWaySelections, activityType);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        }
    };
    Intent requestIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FitnessRecordingService.class);
    requestIntent.setAction(FitnessRecordingService.GET_FITNESS_RECORD_ACTION);
    bindService(requestIntent, sConn, 0);
}
```

if connecting is done - create fragment and fill data

```
private void callGPSFragment() {
        ...
        GPSServicePresenter gpsServicePresenter = new GPSServicePresenter();
        showGPSFragment(gpsServicePresenter);
```

call fragment

```
    public void showGPSFragment(GPSServicePresenter gpsServicePresenter) {
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     transaction.replace(R.id.body_fragent, gpsServicePresenter);
     Fragment oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SplashFragment.tag());
     if (oldFragment != null) {
         transaction.remove(oldFragment);
     }
     transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: Which is line number `712 ` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Based on the exception, I'm guessing it's the last one:
`transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();`

Comment: Yes.It's true. Exception shows after commitAllowingStateLoss()

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that connections to services happen asynchronously and there is a chance that `onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder)` is called after you activity has been destroyed.

In order to fix this, you could use the `Activity.isDestroyed()` function (and/or `isFinishing()` if you want to support older versions of Android) to check the state of your activity and prevent interactions after it's been destroyed:

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    if (service != null && !isDestroyed()) {
        callGPSFragment(status, mapWaySelections, activityType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, friend. I thought about it, but I need to show this fragment. No idea how to do it in this case? I don't know, may be recreate the Activiti or something else?

Comment: Depends on the use case. If the activity has been destroyed because the user has left it (e.g. pressing the back button) then you probably don't want to show nothing. If showing the activity is still relevant then you might want to call `startActivity()` again.

Comment: hm. And send some data from service by intent. Great! I try this